# Change bar chart series color using Google Apps Script, EmbeddedChart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, bar-chart

I have an embedded bar chart in a Google sheet. I'd like to change the color of the bars using Google Apps Script. I tried

```
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  var chart = charts[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('title', 'New Title')
    .setOption('series.0.color', 'red')
    .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
```

The title gets updated, but the color does not.
I also tried `.setColors()`, with no effect either.
When a build a new chart (`newChart()`) with the same
`.setOption('series.0.color', 'red')`, the specified color is used.

Comment: Which type of chart are you creating? Can you share the creation of the chart as well? Are you using Apps Script or the Visualization API? @Boris

Comment: @ale13 It's a bar chart. Using Apps Script.

Answer (score 4):

[This article](https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/03/04/adding-title-of-vaxis-to-embedded-chart-on-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/) gave me a clue

Using the notation `.setOption('series', {0: {color: 'red'}})` did the trick!

Is there a reason the original notation doesn't work for modify, only for create? Is that a bug that I should report?

Comment: Recently, I pursued this issue ([this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/ovqkum/how_to_modify_strokes_for_a_stacked_column_chart/h7j0nwi/?context=3)). 
I found what options are allowed for `setOption()` method [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/chart-configuration-options#bar-chart-configuration-options). No `series.0.color` style options were there. 
So I don't know why `series.0.color` style options are allowed for creation.

I have concluded that EmbeddedChart is not the same as the ordinary Chart.